# Seeing chi square minimization problem as calculus of variation problem

Tags: chi-squared-test, calculus

My question will be less informative because right now I myself don't know where I am heading. Basically I want to know that whether it is possible to think a chi-square minimization problem as a calculus of variation problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really. A chi-square minimization problem seeks the parameterized function that minimizes some quantity.  A calculus of variation problem seeks the arbitrary function that minimizes some quantity. The degrees of freedom of the former are a finite number of parameters. The degrees of freedom of the latter are infinite.